# A counterexample about orthogonal complement.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples

In our functional analysis course we have shown that if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $M$ is a closed subspace then $H=M\oplus M^{\perp}$.However I know that this is not necessarily true if $M$ is not closed.I considered the example $\ell_2$ which is a Hilbert space with the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n\overline{y_n}$.I took this example because the proof of the theorem stated above is due to the fact that for each $x\in H$ there is an $x'\in M$ such that $\|x-x'\|\leq \|x-y\|$ for all $y\in M$.Then we could write $x=x'+(x-x')$ where $x'\in M$ and $x-x'\in M^{\perp}$.So if I take a space where this projection fails to exist,then we can find a counterexample possibly.So,we take $M=\text{span}\{e_1,e_2,...\}$ which is not closed,so that there exists $x=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...)\in \ell_2$ such that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset M$ given by $x_n=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{n},0,0,...)$ such that $x_n\to x$  but $x\notin M$.Then the orthogonal complement $M^{\perp}=\{x\in \ell_2:\langle x,e_k\rangle=0,\forall k\in \mathbb N\}=\{0\}$.So that $M+M^{\perp}\neq \ell_2$.Is this a proper way to think of such counterexamples?

Comment: yes. this is the standard example for the fact you are discussing.

Comment: The fact is not true for any nonclosed $M$, so there is no need to look for a specific counterexample. Indeed the space $M^\perp$ is closed. Moreover $(M^\perp)^\perp =\overline{M}.$ Therefore $\mathcal{H}=M^\perp\oplus \overline{M}.$ Since $M\subsetneq \overline{M}$ we get $M^\perp \oplus M\subsetneq \mathcal{H}.$